# Result class to pass between project layers

Tags: c#

**Problem Statement**

I've seen something similar with [Remora Results](https://github.com/Nihlus/Remora.Results), but I can't use it because of the license. My goal is to instantiate a `FooBarResult` either from a result or from an error, then pass it to another component. In the other component, it is checked for `IsSuccesful` and depending on that, either `BadRequest(FooBarResult.ErrorMsg)` or `Ok(FooBarResult.Payload)` is executed (just as an example).

I've heard about the Either monad, but I can't really make sense of it. Instead, I tried to do it the simple way with the `FooBarResult` class. However, it is not really safe to use, since I could still use the object in the wrong way.

```
public class FooBarResult
{
    public bool IsSuccessful { get; set; }
    public string? Payload { get; set; }
    public string? ErrorMsg { get; set; }

    public FooBarResult(string error)
    {
        IsSuccessful = false;
        ErrorMsg = error;
    }
    
    public FooBarResult(string payload) // that won't work
    {
        IsSuccessful = true;
        Payload = payload;
    }
}
```

**Question**

How can one make a result class, that contains payload and error message, depending on the success of the operation generating the result? Can payload maybe even be a generic T object and the error also?

Comment: Do you have special purposes for setting _string_ as nullable? String is a reference type and always nullable.

Comment: Maybe add static Factorymethods: `FromResult(string)` and `FromError(string)` ? And since you've been considering 3rd parties already: Maybe check [Ardalis/Result](https://github.com/ardalis/Result)

Comment: How about `public FooBarResult(string stringValue, bool isError = false)`?

Comment: _"Can payload maybe even be a generic T object and the error also?"_ - Sure. But for the Error, this doesn't make too much sense, though. What makes a good Error representation, anyway: A descriptive text, maybe a code and maybe a causing exception, right?

Comment: @RelativeLayouter - Since C#8, you can set up the compiler so that reference types are NOT nullable by default so that you don't have to have null checks everywhere

Comment: If you're not aware, that library just changed (2 days ago) from AGPL to LGPL. I don't know if that makes a difference to whether you can use it or not.

Comment: @Fildor The static factory methods are a fantastic idea, but I can still use it "wrong". IsSuccessful can be 'false', yet I can still try to access the payload, which may be null.

Comment: @jkbx I don't think you can 100% avoid that if you want/need to represent both error and success in one abstraction. You _could_ of course implement the getters to throw some Exception if used "incorrectly", so you "fail fast" if there's a usage error in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the "avoid wrong usage" part, you *could* do something like this (I personally wouldn't, but hey... )

```
public class FooBarResult
{
     public bool IsSuccessful {get; set;}

     // just doing one to demonstrate
     private string _payload;
     public string Payload
     {
         // InvalidOperationException is the ...
         // "The exception that is thrown when a method call is invalid 
         //  for the object's current state."
         get { 
               if(IsSuccessful) return _payload; 
               throw new InvalidOperationException(); 
             }
         set { _payload = value; }
     }
}
```

See https://dotnetfiddle.net/fqpSQS

For reference:

[InvalidOperationException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.invalidoperationexception?view=net-6.0)

**Mind** : This may get you into trouble as soon as you try to serialize / deserialize.

Comment: That works for me. Serializing/Deserializing the result won't work, is that what you mean?

Comment: It wouldn't work out of the box, yes. A serializer may try to read all the properties, of course not aware of semantic realtionships between them ( "X is only valid if Y is true ...).